# Twitter Search API query with hashtag returning returning "Could not authenticate you”,”code”:32

Tags: twitter, postman, twitter-oauth

I have scoured the web to try and find an answer to what seems to be a simple solution but unable to come across one.

I am using Postman. On the Authorisation tab, I have entered the details as defined in the Twitter Application Management.

In the header, I have a key of `Authorization` and value of

```
OAuth oauth_consumer_key="my-consumer-key",
oauth_token="my-consumer-token",
oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",
oauth_timestamp="1538075001",
oauth_nonce="zXeiLqV5GzK",
oauth_version="1.0",
oauth_signature="SYdcrIrRT6jdgo57b1qP9a9THcc%253D"
```

When I run a GET request for `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=test` I get the expect results.

However, trying to search for a hashtag 
`https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23test&include_entities=true` I get the following in the response body

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": 32,
            "message": "Could not authenticate you."
        }
    ]
}
```

with a status of `401: Authorization Required`

Why would this be the case, would there be a step I missed in setting up or can you not search for hashtags on the free version?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please try TinyTwitter

Comment: Did you fix that?

Comment: @BorisT unfortunately not, used Twit package instead

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to use OAuth2

Twitter OAuth1 seems to have issue with url encoding.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using OAuth2 too. Requesting Bearer's Token to `https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token` and giving it App Consumer API keys as authorization credentials.

Reference can be found [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/api-reference/token)

Comment: This answer is very brief, it would be helpful to add more explanation rather than simply a link.